# How to recieve touches began event inside a subview?

Tags: iphone, events, touch, gesture-recognition, subviews

I have a view containing two subviews(plain UIviews).  The parent view recognizes touch events like touchesbegan ,ended, etc. but the sub view is not recognizing the touch event. How to make it recognize the touch event. Specifically i need only sub view to recognize  touch events and not parent view. Thanks in advance.

UserInteractionEnabled is set to YES for the views.

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways of dealing with this.

1) Detect the touches in your viewcontroller instead of in a view. You should be able to work out which view contains the point which was touched and from that can decide what to do with the touch (or just throw it away if it wasn't in either view).

2) Create a subclass of UIView and add these to your main view instead of just UIViews. Then you can detect the touches inside your subclass and deal with them accordingly.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. From your first point, how to detect a sub view from touching, when it is overlapped or hidden by another subview?

Comment: That's up to you! You have to make sure that a touch is inside the view you want and also not inside any of the other views above it :)